# JAVA: Metodo, Clases, Variables y subprogramas

Tags: java

Desde el main, quiero llamar a un subprograma de una clase, metiendole un parámetro . Quiero después imprimirlo.

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
String cleartext = "hola";
System.out.println(crypto.Cifrar.encrypt(cleartext.getBytes()));

}

}
```

Esta es mi clase que tengo. Ojo! Creo que me hecho un lio con los parámetros, constructores y demás. A ver si lo podéis probar y mirar que falla.
Gracias.

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;
import static com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64.encode;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public  class Cifrar {

// Definición del tipo de algoritmo a utilizar (AES, DES, RSA)
private final static String alg = "AES";
private final static int keyLength=128;
private final static int ivLength=128;
private final static String cI =  "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private byte [] iv;
private static byte[] aesKeyBytes;
private static IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;


public Cifrar() throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(alg);
    keyGen.init(keyLength, new SecureRandom());
    SecretKey aesKey = keyGen.generateKey();
    aesKeyBytes = aesKey.getEncoded();
    iv = SecureRandom.getSeed(ivLength / 8);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

}
 public Cifrar(byte[]aesKeyBytesQuemePasan, IvParameterSpec ivspecquemePasan) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {


    aesKeyBytes = aesKeyBytesQuemePasan;
    ivParameterSpec = ivspecquemePasan;

}

public void setAesKeyBytes(byte[] aesKeyBytes) {
    this.aesKeyBytes = aesKeyBytes;
}

public void setIv(byte[] iv) {
    this.iv = iv;
}  

public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] cleartext) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cI);
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyBytes, alg);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(cleartext);
    return encrypted;
}

public static byte[] decrypt( byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cI);
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyBytes, alg);
    System.out.println(encrypted);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}

}
```

Este es el fallo que me da:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing argument
at javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec.<init>(SecretKeySpec.java:93)
at crypto.Cifrar.encrypt(Cifrar.java:64)
at crypto.main.main(main.java:22)
```

Muchas gracias :)

Comment: No se es claro cual es la linea 64 que genera la excepción, Y que me perdonen pero creo que esa forma de llamar la clase Cifrar esta mal.
Que me corrijan si me equivoco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTA: Es mejor indicar en el código cuál es la línea de tu programa donde está el fallo (en este caso la línea 64).

El fallo surge en el constructor de `SecretKeySpec`. [Vamos al Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html#SecretKeySpec(byte[],%20java.lang.String)), que nos dice:

> Throws:
>
> IllegalArgumentException - if algorithm is null or key is null or empty.

Revisando el código, aparece:

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] cleartext) throws Exception {
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cI);
  SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyBytes, alg);
```

`alg` es `static final` y tiene el valor "AES". Pero en ningún momento se asigna un valor a `aesKeyBytes`.

El problema es que la clase es una mezcla de métodos y atributos estáticos y de instancia. Si `encrypt` y `decrypt` fueran métodos de instancia (no estáticos), los invocarías sobre una instancia de `Cifrar` inicializada apropiadamente, con uno de los dos constructores, y en los constructores se asignaría el valor de `aesKeyBytes` (suponiendo que no le pasaras un array `null`, claro).

Tal como está, hay un código en los constructores que asigna el valor de la clave, pero como se invocan a los métodos directamente como métodos estáticos, no se ejecuta ningún constructor con la inicialización.

Solución: quita todos los `static` de la clase para que todos los métodos y atributos sean de instancia, crea una instancia de `Cifrar` y llama a sus métodos `encrypt` y `decrypt`.

Comment: Ya más como opinión personal, si estás tan verde en Java te recomiendo no empezar con métodos criptográficos. No porque sean especialmente complicados, sino porque son "cajas negras": cualquier fallo en cualquier detalle te va a dar un programa que, sencillamente, "no funciona". Otros tipos de programas permiten comparar resultados esperados con obtenidos, lo que ayuda a depurarlos (si hago una calculadora y a "3*3" me responde "5", tendré un par de ideas de cuál puede ser el fallo, con criptografía muchas veces no hay ninguna pista.

Comment: Hola Juan. Primero GRACIAS POR TU AYUDA. Yo en primero y en segundo de carrera, las asignaturas de programación saque muy buenas notas. Pero ahora estoy en 4º y tengo que hacer esto, y la verdad, NO ME ACUERDO DE casi NADA, me da mucha pena por que antes sabia. Estoy muy nervioso, tengo que entregar esto el martes y no me sale nada, estoy con el Java dando bandazos como el palo de un ciego. He tenido que irme a dar una vuelta porque me iba a explotar la cabeza. Donde estoy nadie te ayuda y te dejan solo abandonado, y aquí estoy, buscandome las castañas. Probaré lo que me dices.GRACIAS

Comment: Hola Juan, he hecho el cambio, pero ahora no ejecuta bien los codigos de encriptacion y desencriptación.

Comment: Crearé mejor una nueva pregunta, por que esto esta solucionado. Gracias Juan